# Перенос rar-файла на ftp: "Заголовок файла "???" повреждён"

Tags: windows, ftp, архивация

Через бат файл архивирую и переношу файл на фтп, скачиваю его с фтп, пытаюсь открыть пишет:  "Заголовок файла "???" повреждён". Открываю файл перед отправкой на фтп - все нормально. Куда копать?

.bat :

```
@EchoE:cd E:\Trade\Price\Opt\rar.exe a -o+ -r E:\Trade\Price\1.rar *.*ftp -s:E:\Admin\ftp2.txt//del E:\Trade\Price\1.rarexit
```

ftp2.txt :

```
open ...70logpasscd /public_html/.../...send E:\Trade\Price\1.rarbye
```

Comment: Вот всем и интересно, каким способом перейти в бинарный режим =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается в виндовс по умолчанию стоит режим передачи ASCII, с ним доходят поврежденные файлы (как минимум архивные), нужен двоичный режим и проблема решена. Вопрос закройте. Спасибо.

```
open ...70logpasscd /public_html/.../...binarysend E:\Trade\Price\1.rarbye
```